# Why is the activation stored procedure not triggering on my SQL Server QUEUE?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SERVICE BROKER and QUEUE functionality in SQL Server. I've mostly been trying to follow some examples:

- https://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/configuring-service-broker
- https://www.sqlshack.com/using-the-sql-server-service-broker-for-asynchronous-processing/

I can get the manual processing working just fine. If I call a SP that processes the queue, it works as expected. If I understand it correctly, setting the `ACTIVATION, PROCEDURE_NAME` for the QUEUE *should* set this to automatically process messages sent to the queue. However, that is NOT what I am seeing in SQL SERVER v12.0.6433.1

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    CREATE TABLE #DONE
    (
        ID INT
    );

    CREATE MESSAGE TYPE CUSTOM_TYPE
        AUTHORIZATION XYZ_USER
        VALIDATION = NONE;
    GO

    CREATE CONTRACT POST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MESSAGE_CONTRACT
        (CUSTOM_TYPE SENT BY ANY);
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE TESTING.PROCESS_QUEUE AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @HANDLE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        DECLARE @MESSAGE_TYPE SYSNAME;
        DECLARE @MESSAGE INT;

        WHILE (1 = 1)
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRANSACTION;
                WAITFOR (
                RECEIVE TOP (1)
                    @HANDLE = CONVERSATION_HANDLE,
                    @MESSAGE_TYPE = MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME,
                    @MESSAGE = MESSAGE_BODY FROM TESTING.CUSTOM_QUEUE), TIMEOUT 1000;

                IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                        BREAK;
                    END

                INSERT INTO #DONE (ID) VALUES (@MESSAGE);
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END
    END
    GO

    CREATE QUEUE TESTING.CUSTOM_QUEUE
        WITH STATUS = ON,
        RETENTION = OFF,
        ACTIVATION (
            PROCEDURE_NAME = TESTING.PROCESS_QUEUE,
            MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5,
            EXECUTE AS SELF
            ),
        POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING ( STATUS = OFF );
    GO

    CREATE SERVICE CUSTOM_TYPE_SERVICE
        AUTHORIZATION XYZ_USER
        ON QUEUE TESTING.CUSTOM_QUEUE
        (POST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MESSAGE_CONTRACT);
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE TESTING.INSERT_INTO_QUEUE @ID INT AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        DECLARE @SERVICE SYSNAME;
        SET @SERVICE = 'CUSTOM_TYPE_SERVICE';

        DECLARE @CONTRACT SYSNAME;
        SET @CONTRACT = 'POST_CUSTOM_TYPE_MESSAGE_CONTRACT';

        DECLARE @HANDLE UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        BEGIN
            DIALOG CONVERSATION @HANDLE
            FROM SERVICE @SERVICE
            TO SERVICE @SERVICE
            ON CONTRACT @CONTRACT
            WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

        SEND ON CONVERSATION @HANDLE MESSAGE TYPE CUSTOM_TYPE(@ID);
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END
    GO

    EXEC TESTING.INSERT_INTO_QUEUE 1;
    EXEC TESTING.INSERT_INTO_QUEUE 2;
    EXEC TESTING.INSERT_INTO_QUEUE 3;

    SELECT *
    FROM TESTING.CUSTOM_QUEUE;

    SELECT * FROM #DONE;

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

I see 3 records in `TESTING.CUSTOM_QUEUE` and 0 records in `#DONE`.

Am I overlooking something here? Or is there a missing DB setting I need? I am wondering if using a custom SCHEMA (instead of DBO) is causing issues as well. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Running all this in a transaction seems like a bad idea. The service broker will run under  different session, so won't see your tables and config at all until you commit. Note also that nested transaction don't really exist in SQL Server

Comment: Running it not inside a transaction produces the same results, unfortunately. I also changed the #DONE temp table to a real table. Same, same.

Comment: The first obvious question is - how long are you waiting after inserting data into the queue before checking the results? Service broker is inherently asynchronous and so if you run everything you have above in one batch you would indeed see the results you're seeing but some time later I'd expect activation to kick in and process the records in the queue. The next thing I'd look at is if the procedure is being called at all by using an XE session. You can check if it's working by manually calling the proc and see it show up in the XE.

Comment: Huzzah! Running it as separate calls shows expected results. Thanks! @BenThul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the loop based on the brief conversation in the comments above, the key observation is that you're inserting into a queue. The processing of that queue by (in this case internal activation) is inherently asynchronous. If you check the queue right after having put items into it, odds are that those items will not have been processed yet. But if you wait some time, whatever is processing the queue should do what it needs to.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms171601(v=sql.105)) is a great article explaining how activation happens.